# How to apply a function row by row in merge syntax in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, apply

I have two dataframes:

df1:

[image: df1]

df2:

[image: df2]

If i map the date in df2 from df1, using below merge command, which gives me output same as df1,

```
df2.merge(df1, how = 'left', on='Category')
```

But actually i need the output as below,

where, if only one date is returned, assign to the category

if multiple dates are returned and all are unique, assign the unique date once

if multiple dates are returned and if more than one unique date is available, assign None.

Required output:

[image: Required output]

can any one help with this, since i'm struggling here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should try to specify a loop, with the conditions you have mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**STEPS:**

1. Use `groupby` and `filter` the required groups from the 1st dataframe.
2. `drop the duplicates` from df1
3. `perform merge` with this updated `df1`.

```
df1 = df1.groupby('Category').filter(
    lambda x: x['Date'].nuique().eq(1)).drop_duplicates()
df2.merge(df1, how='left', on='Category')
```